# Can mutt delete message locally but retain it on server?

Tags: email, mutt

When using mutt I don't want all the messages to be cached, which could take up a lot of disk space. But if I purge an email, it also gets deleted on the server side, which is undesired because I may need to reference it in future. Is it possible to automatically clean up cached old messages when it's >100MB, while keeping those messages as they are on server and never retrieve them back to my laptop?

Comment: is this question still valid? I think the disk space doesn't bother anyone for long years.
Anyway, I don't think mutt can do this, but there can be some option on the server. f.e.: GMail has *Folder size limits* in it's IMAP configuration where You can set maximum number of messages served from every IMAP folder

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you mind rephrasing your comment into an answer which I can mark as accepted to close this question? After, even no is an answer as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot do that directly in neomutt.

But in GMail and maybe other e-mail providers you can set limit for number of messages beeing fetched from folder/label over IMAP.

`GMail` > `Settings` > `Forwarding and POP/IMAP` (IMAP access section) under `Folder size limits`
**Limit IMAP folders to contain no more than this many messages**